# JAX-WS Handler add to WS Client via configuration WebSphere AS 8.x.x.x

Tags: web-services, websphere-8

How to add a custom handler for soap webclient(managed client) to WebSphere AS 8.x.x.x via configuration. The handler was added to WebSphere AS(exist in classpath) without changes in application(code changes)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Knowledge Center of how to implement web service client handler https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/twbs_jaxwshandler.html.
According to this, you must set the @HandlerChain annotation to the web service class.

Regards

Comment: Thank you. I know that you can add @HandlerChain to the web service but How can I add a handler without changing artifact .ear or .war? Such as add binding to managed client, policy, etc. I imagine it as you have artifact(.jar) with the handler that extend AbstractHandler. The next step add to WebSphere AS classpath and configure with WS AS console.